# Installing blender in ubuntu libopenimageio2.1 problem

Tags: python, installation

I'm trying to install blender via `sudo apt install blender`

but it gives the following error

> ```
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  blender : Depends: libopenimageio2.1 (>= 2.1.10.1~dfsg0) but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> ```

I ran `sudo apt search libopenimageio2.1` and it outputs:

> ```
> libopenimageio2.1/focal 2.1.12.0~dfsg0-1 amd64
>   Library for reading and writing images - runtime
> ```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by recursively installing the `sudo apt install libopenimageio2.1`

and the all it's dependent packages